# R, Assign a group ID to combinations of values in another observation ID variable

Tags: r, grouping, ids

Assume that I have several years of personal data, in which a Personal ID (indiv) identifies individuals across years, but the household ID (househ) only assigns household relation *within* a year.

Example:

```
libary(dplyr)
test_01 <- data.frame(indiv=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),househ=c(1,1,2,3,4,4),time=rep(1,6)) #1&2 form a household, 3 and 4 are single, 5&6 form a household
test_02 <- data.frame(indiv=c(2,3,4,5,6,7),househ=c(1,2,2,3,3,4),time=rep(2,6)) #1 exits, so 2 is now a new household, 3&4 now form a new household, 5&6 still do, 7 enters
test_03 <- data.frame(indiv=c(2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10),househ=c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6),time=rep(3,8)) #according to logic above
data_test_panel <- bind_rows(test_01,test_02,test_03)
```

The desired time-consistent household variable would be:

```
data_test_panel$true_household <- c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,4,4,7,5,6,6,8,7,9,9,10)
```

So far I tried:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data_test_panel)[,cons_household := .GRP,.(time,househ)] # where cons_household is the new household ID. However, this doesn't give the same household ID across time but assigns new values for every appearance of a household.
```

Thank you kindly for all your help!
/Severin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list column of unique individuals in a given household at each time period. We can then take the group number by that column.

#### `dplyr` approach

This is much nicer than the `data.table` approach:

```r
library(dplyr)
data_test_panel |>
    mutate(
        indiv_in_household = list(indiv),
        .by = c(househ, time)
    ) |>
    mutate(
        cons_household = cur_group_id(),
        .by = indiv_in_household
    )
```

Note this uses [per-operation grouping](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_by.html) with the `.by` parameter which [requires at least](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2023/02/dplyr-1-1-0-per-operation-grouping/) `dplyr v1.1.0`.

#### `data.table` approach

The syntax for this is much more complicated because `data.table` will automatically unroll your list column into a vector if you try to make it `list(indiv)` by group.

```r
data_test_panel[, indiv_in_household := .SD[
    , .(split(
        rep(indiv, length(indiv)),
        rep(seq(length(indiv)), each = length(indiv))
    )),
    .(househ, time)
]$V1]

head(data_test_panel)
#    indiv househ  time true_household indiv_in_household
#    <num>  <num> <num>          <num>             <list>
# 1:     1      1     1              1                1,2
# 2:     2      1     1              1                1,2
# 3:     3      2     1              2                  3
# 4:     4      3     1              3                  4
# 5:     5      4     1              4                5,6
# 6:     6      4     1              4                5,6
```

Also `data.table` doesn't support grouping by list columns so we need to use `toString()`, which is OK in this case but in general is not ideal as you have to think through the format of the column to ensure it will not somehow cause ambiguity leading two distinct groups to be merged.

```r
data_test_panel[, cons_household := .GRP, sapply(indiv_in_household, toString)]

data_test_panel[cons_household != true_household]
# Empty data.table (0 rows and 6 cols): indiv,househ,time,true_household,cons_household,indiv_in_household
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this incredibly detailed answer! The noted differences between the dplyr and data.table solution is very insightful. In the dplyr solution, I get an error code of Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `.by = c(househ, time)`.
x `.by` must be size 20 or 1, not 40.
But I think I should be able to figure that one out myself.
Thank you kindly!

Comment: Hm, curious, I also applied it to the example data. But nevermind, the data.table approach works perfectly fine.

Comment: @SamR +1 for the very instructive write-up and the `dplyr` answer. With some effort, I've come up with a better solution for the `data.table` case which I've added as an answer

Comment: @Tobo I like how you used `match()` to avoid `toString()` - that could be done here as well e.g. `data_test_panel[, cons_household := match(indiv_in_household, unique(indiv_in_household))]`, which I think is better (and as it avoids `sapply()` almost certainly faster).

Answer (score 1):

### **A `data.table` approach that *is* reasonably nice**

As the previous answer shows, `data.table`'s handling of list columns doesn't lend itself to the `dplyr`-style solution in which the list column of members per annual household is broadcast to all rows of the data, and then grouped-by to create the IDs.

However, we can use the following: (1) Collapse (instead of broadcasting) to a list column with a single row per household/year. (2) Create the ID as the index of each annual household in a list of unique households from all years. (3) Uncollapse the list column.

```
(data_test_panel
  [, .(hh_indivs = list(indiv)), by=.(househ, time)                # collapse
   ][, hh_id := match(hh_indivs, unique(hh_indivs))                # index
    ][, .(indiv = unlist(hh_indivs), hh_id), by=.(househ, time)])  # uncollapse
```

This avoids the complicated code to mimic the broadcasted list column, and the problematic use of `toString()` to enable a groupby.